# stored procedure in mysql returning null

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following table created in mysql database.

```
create table stud_info(Student_ID int,Name varchar(10),Class varchar(10),Marks int)
```

I have also created a stored procedure to retrieve the name given the `id` like below:

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure selectEmp2(IN num1 INT,OUT name varchar(20))
BEGIN
select Name INTO name from myDB.stud_info where Student_ID=num1;
END//
```

When I am calling the stored procedure , I am getting `null` value. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think your stored procedure should work, but I would advise giving names to parameters that are likely to be unique.  I also prefer explicit variable assignment, because `select into` can mean different things.  Does this work?

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure selectEmp2(IN in_num1 INT, OUT out_name varchar(20))
BEGIN
    select si.Name into out_name
    from myDB.stud_info si
    where si.Student_ID = in_num1;
END;//
```

Comment: The above statement is giving error when running through the sql developer

    Error report -
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use   near ':= si.Name
        from myDB.stud_info si
        where si.Student_ID = in_num1;  
END' at line 3

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure selectEmp2(IN _num1 INT,OUT _name varchar(20))
BEGIN
select Name INTO _name 
from myDB.stud_info 
where Student_ID=_num1;
END//
```

Comment: And how do I invoke the stored procedure?

Comment: windows and working on sql developer and mysql client